# PHP Class properties are empty when initialized in constructor

Tags: php, class, properties

I'm writing a very simple php class to do some tests, but the variables that i initialize within the constructor remain empty:

```
class Zip {

private $root;


public function _construct() {
    $this->root=dirname(__DIR__);
}

public function print(){ echo $this->root;};

}
```

When i print the variable, ir returns nothing, and after checking it's simply null.
Why is this not working?

Comment: Unnecessary semicolon after the print function? `public function print(){ echo $this->root;};
` Not sure if that’s causing the issue though. Also try to echo something from the constructor just to see if it actually gets run.

Comment: Probably because you missed one underscore? It's `__construct()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply try it as:-

```
class Zip {

    private $root;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->root = dirname(__DIR__);
    }

    public function print()
    { 
      echo $this->root;
    }
}
```

After that:-

```
$object = new Zip();
echo $object->print();
```

the constructor should have __ and you are missing class closing }, remove the last semicolon, you don't need it.

Comment: Was missing an underscore.